# exercise to write a code to insert 15 numbers(between 0 - 7)

Tags: python-3.x

help with the following exercise
. write a code to insert 15 numbers(between 0 - 7) in list
convert the list to tuple
print count of each number between 0 - 7
find the max and min in the tuple
print the sorted tuple

##insert 15 numbers(between 0 - 7) in list

```
numbers1 = []
numbers2 = []
for i in range(1,8):
    numbers1.append(i)
    for x in range(15,30):
    numbers2.append(x)
    numbers1.insert(-1,numbers2)
    print(numbers1)
## convert the list to tuple
tuple1 = tuple(numbers1)
print(tuple1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use '.sort' to arrange a list into alphabetical order, numerical order etc. You'll be looking for something like this:

```
#Define a list
number_list = []

#loop 15 times
for number in range(5):

    #this while loop loops within the for loop until a valid input is given
    while True:

        #try catch statements when attempting to convert to integer
        try:
            #define number_input as an integer input
            number_input = int(input("Please enter a number:\n"))
        #if failed to convert to an integer
        except:
            #print warning
            print("Please enter a valid number\n")
            #'continue' starts the program back at the begining of the while loop
            continue

        #if the number is equal to or below 7, and equal or above 0
        if(number_input <= 7 and number_input >= 0):
            #end the while loop
            break
        #if not between the values
        else:
            #print warning
            print("Please enter a valid number\n")

    #append integer to the list and go continue the for loop
    number_list.append(number_input)

#sort the list in order of smallest to largest
number_list.sort()
#convert number_list to tuple
number_list = tuple(number_list)

print(number_list)
```

Comment: write a code to insert 15 numbers(between 0 - 7) in list
convert the list to tuple
print count of each number between 0 - 7
find the max and min in the tuple
print the sorted tuple

I run the code and the output was (4, 5, 6, 7, 7)

Comment: Use min() max() to find the minimum and maximum value in a tuple

Comment: Thank you, for #loop 15 times should 5 change to 15 ?
for number in range(5):

also what the right way to do the count of each number between 0 - 7